# Positive reals satisfy $ \sum_{i=1}^{24} x_i = 1 $, determine maximum of following quantity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

So, positive reals satisfy the following

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{24} x_i = 1 $$

And I need to find maximum of the following quantity.

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \sqrt{x_i}\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x_i} } \right) $$

Now, using Cauchy Schwarz inequality, I got

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \sqrt{x_i}\right)^2 \leqslant \underbrace{(1+1+\cdots + 1)}_{\text{24 times}} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} x_i \right) $$

This leads to

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \sqrt{x_i}\right) \leqslant  \sqrt{24} $$

I am stuck with other part. I can get the minimum of the following using similar technique.

$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x_i} } \right) $$

But I need to have maximum of this quantity, so that I can combine the two. Any hints will help.

Comment: @jyrki-lahtonen I tried to use AM-GM-HM and Cauchy-Schwarz. But can't seem to get what I want. I just let all $x_i$ equal to each other and then I get max value as $24^2/5$ for the original expression. But that is a hack. I want to see how to bound the second sum to some upper value

Comment: Scratch that. A silly mistake.

Comment: I think the other factor is maximized at the vertices of the simplex. That is, at the points where one variable is equal to $1$ and the rest are zero. This suggests that you cannot get the answer by upper bounding the two factors separately. Mind you, I still share your suspicion that the extremum occurs at the point where the variables are all equal. It is easy to convince yourself of this by plotting in the case of 3 variables.

Comment: @jyrki-lahtonen I found the answer and posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can bound the second sum as follows. Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have the following.

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x_i}} \right)^2 \leqslant \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{(1+x_i)} \right)\underbrace{(1+1+\cdots +1)}_{\text{24 times}} $$

$$  \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x_i}} \right)^2 \leqslant 24 \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{(1+x_i)} \right) \, \cdots \cdots \cdots(1)
$$

Now, I will use Hölder's inequality.

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{(1+x_i)} \right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} (1+x_i) \right)^{1/2} \leqslant \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{24} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x_i}}\right) \left(\sqrt{1+x_i}\right) \right] $$

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{(1+x_i)} \right)^{1/2} \sqrt{25} \leqslant 24  $$

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{(1+x_i)} \right)  \leqslant \frac{24^2}{25} $$

$$ 24 \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{(1+x_i)} \right)  \leqslant \frac{24^3}{25} $$

So, combining with equation $(1)$, I get,

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x_i}} \right)^2 \leqslant \frac{24^3}{25} $$

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x_i}} \right) \leqslant \frac{24^{3/2}}{5} $$

Finally, combining the two sums, I get

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \sqrt{x_i} \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x_i}} \right) \leqslant \sqrt{24} \,\frac{24^{3/2}}{5} $$

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \sqrt{x_i} \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x_i}} \right) \leqslant \frac{24^{2}}{5} $$

Hope that helps